# Image not displaying in loop Vue.js

Tags: image, vue.js, gallery

I am trying to display 9 different images in a loop using `v-for`.

But, they are are not showing. If I show it without any loop, it works.

I am extracting the right resource but, still, it won't display.

This is my code:

```
<img class="list-complete-img" src="../assets/g1.jpg" alt="" /> //This works
<div v-for="item in data.items" :key="item.id">
    <div>
        {{ item.src }} // Just to check if I am printing right
    </div>
    <img class="list-complete-img" :src="item.src" :alt="item.src" /> // This does not work
</div>
```

Now the result that I am getting is:

[image: This is the snippet I am receiving]

This is my `data.json`:

```
 "items": [
    { "id": "1", "src": "../assets/g1.jpg", "tags": ["all", "tag1"] },
    { "id": "2", "src": "../assets/g2.png", "tags": ["all", "tag2"] },
    { "id": "3", "src": "../assets/g3.png", "tags": ["all", "tag2"] },
    { "id": "4", "src": "../assets/g4.png", "tags": ["all", "tag1"] },
    { "id": "5", "src": "../assets/g5.png", "tags": ["all", "tag1"] },
    { "id": "6", "src": "../assets/g6.png", "tags": ["all", "tag2"] },
    { "id": "7", "src": "../assets/g7.jpg", "tags": ["all", "tag1"] },
    { "id": "8", "src": "../assets/g8.png", "tags": ["all", "tag2"] },
    { "id": "9", "src": "../assets/g9.png", "tags": ["all", "tag2"] }
  ]
```

---

**EDIT**

So far, I have observed that the problem lies with the `src`. If I am using an image link, it is working just fine. But, not with a local image(only if I used bunch of local images in a loop and working just fine in single). So, what I can do is put the file directory here. I would recommend if anyone of you can try on your local computer and try to upload images from your file directory in a loop and post it here.

[image: File Directory]

[image: Inspect Element as required]

---

**SOLVED**

It needed this statement exactly: `require`, the path directory and image name.

```
<div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
    <div>
        {{ item.src }}
    </div>
    <img
        class="list-complete-img"
        :src="require(`../assets/${item.src}`)"
        :alt="item.src"
    />
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible that you inspect the element when it has been rendered on the browser and post a screenshot?

Comment: There is nothing in the console with no error. Just read it I have edited the problem.

Answer (score 4):

This is issue has to do with the following quote of Evan You, which can be found [here](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/126):

> Because the imagePath is only rendered by Vue at runtime, Webpack has no chance of rewriting it.

Your `JavaScript` code needs to be like this:

```js
export default {
  name: "App",
  data: function () {
    return {
      items: [
        { id: "1", src: "logo.png", tags: ["all", "tag1"] },
        { id: "2", src: "logo.png", tags: ["all", "tag2"] },
        { id: "3", src: "logo.png", tags: ["all", "tag2"] },
        { id: "4", src: "logo.png", tags: ["all", "tag1"] },
        { id: "5", src: "logo.png", tags: ["all", "tag1"] },
        { id: "6", src: "logo.png", tags: ["all", "tag2"] },
        { id: "7", src: "logo.png", tags: ["all", "tag1"] },
        { id: "8", src: "logo.png", tags: ["all", "tag2"] },
        { id: "9", src: "logo.png", tags: ["all", "tag2"] },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getImgUrl: function (imagePath) {
      return require('@/assets/' + imagePath);
    }
  }
};
```

Afterwards, you need to call your `getImgUrl` function by passing the filename. Your `HTML` will be like this:

```html
<div id="app">
  <img class="list-complete-img" src="./assets/logo.png" />
  <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
    <img class="list-complete-img" :src="getImgUrl(item.src)" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Since I do not have access to your images, I have taken the liberty to use the Vue logo as an image.

In summary, the above problem has to do that when `Vue` compiles, it takes all the assets and puts them in another folder like the image below:

[image]

Follow this pattern and your example will also work. Enjoy!

EDIT: If you want, you can have your static assets placed in the public folder. In that way, you will be able to write static paths for your assets.

Comment: This has made me come closer to discovering my problem and data.items does not matter since I am using separate data.json file rather than using it in the same file that's why I have written that like this. But I have edited the problem please check because of you guys I know the problem lies with the src.

Comment: @khemangarg I need you to inspect the element when it has been rendered on the browser and post a screenshot?

Comment: edited and posted

Comment: @khemangarg I have edited my answer to your question. Give it a try and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

try this: `v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i"`

Comment: Nope still not working. Problem is not that it doesn't print the correct thing. It does print correctly but problem is it's not displaying the IMG as if I am putting the wrong SRC which is put in single image it's fine.

Comment: write your code on codepen

Answer (score 0):

To use dynamic images, use require(). Change what you have to this.

```js
<div id="app">
    <div v-for="item in data.items" :key="item.id">
        <img ... :src="require(item.src)" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was hoping that this would work but no still not working with this the page goes all blank. But I have edited the problem please check because of you guys I know the problem lies with the src.

Comment: @khemangarg, please could you post your `data` property with the `items` property? Also, please show me where your data.json is imported. I actually thought `items` was a data property. I will edit my answer. I have replaced `items` with `data.items`.

Comment: Tony man I have voted you. I had a strong feeling with this one =. You were right about require part. All i needed to is add path directory inside require and not in my data. so the code snippet for this is: <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
        <div>
          {{ item.src }}
        </div>
        <img
          class="list-complete-img"
          :src="require(`../assets/${item.src}`)"
          :alt="item.src"
        />
      </div>

Comment: I am happy your challenge has been solved, @khemangarg. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a for loop which may help correct me if I am wrong